# Section break for word doc programmatically

Tags: python, powershell, ms-word

How can i give section break after each page so that i can get different header/footer on each page. programmatically in python or power shell.

Comment: Are you generating the OpenXML doc manually using Python, or are you using some library?

Comment: docx library fo python

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or link on where i can get such things using "openxml doc manually using python" (things mentoine din question)

Comment: I don't know of a tutorial, but the format for the files can be found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee908652.aspx (it's quite a large specification).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecifications/hh237328.aspx is a good intro and contains links to other resources.  The docx format is basically a zip container with xml files inside.  When figuring things like this out in the past, I've found it helpful to create a document that has the elements I need, then rename from .docx to .zip and extract.  The section related elements should be in `word/document.xml`.